# Adsense ads doesn't appear on wordpress home page?

Tags: wordpress, adsense

Does any one has idea why they don't appear on home page, and in some single posts?
If anyone wants to check the code, here is my website:
http://videoshqip.tv>

`NOTE`: Logout first from facebook if you don't want to see the request to accept my facebook app, than visit my site!

Answer (score 1):

If you have recently created the ad block, it will take some time to start showing.

If not, [check this](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10036).

Comment: Yes i have readed the instructions on google page, but i don't think that this is the proble. I have installed someplugins and insertet some javascript codes manually so maybe this is making problems, for that i requested someone to check my source code on my homepage. Any way thank you @Mark